# Как добавить картинку в виждеже на wordpress не указывая полный путь?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Всем привет! Подскажите, как можно добавить картинку в виджете wordpressa? Вот так

```
<a href="#">
  <img src="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/banner.jpg" alt="banner">
</a>
```

и вот так добавить не могу, т.к. допустима только вставка html

```
<a href="#"><img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/images/aternus.png" alt="" width="" height="" />
</a>
```

А вот так картинка не показывается на страницах пагинации..

```
<a href="#">
  <img src="../../wp-content/uploads/2015/07/banner.jpg" alt="banner">
</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел ответ - нужно просто установить плагин **Image Widget**

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="#">
  <img src="/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/banner.jpg" alt="banner">
</a>
```

абсолютный путь без домена